# Passportjs keep users logged in

Tags: facebook, passport.js

I am currently using the passportjs-facebook to enable facebook login. It works great within a session but as soon as the user closes the browser and renavigate to the site, he is signed out and need to sign back in. It is not a facebook issue since the signin is instantaneous

The weirdest part is that the login behaviour works fine on localhost, meaning that if the user closes the browser and renavigate to the localhost, his session is kept

What could be causing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a session store? if you are just using express session. The session isn't persisted. If you use mongo or redis to store sessions that should fix the issue